# How do I load a JavaScript file?

Tags: 8, javascript

I used the following code.

#### libraries.yml

```
    my_module.admin:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/my-module.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

#### my_module.module

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function my_module_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {

$attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'js/my_module';
  // $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = array('my_module', 'admin');
}
```

#### my_module/js/my_module.js

```
(function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
    Drupal.behaviors.my_module = {
      attach: function(context, settings) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert("hello");
            console.log('Loaded');
          }
        };
      })(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

I have tried many other changes, but the JavaScript file is not used.

I have ported Drupal 7 code that implements `hook_boot()` and includes that JavaScript file, to Drupal 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme). In your case, the library name is wrong. The right format for the name is *module_name/libraries_name*.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function my_module_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/my_module.admin';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following changes worked for me :

```
$attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/my_module.admin';
```

and

```
my_module.admin:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/my_module.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```